# cannot create taxonomy terms using hook_enable solved!

Tags: taxonomy-terms

i want to create 1 taxonomy vocabulary and 1 taxonomy term using drupal's hook_enable. but when i enable the custom module, it create only the taxonomy vocabulary. And if i disable and enable the module, the taxonomy term will be created without problem. the code is as below:

```
 $sql = "SELECT vid FROM {taxonomy_vocabulary} WHERE machine_name='article_type'";


$vid = db_query($sql)->fetchField();
    if (!$vid) {
      drupal_set_message(t("Created article type vocabulary"));
      // No vocabulary exists, we'll create one.
      $vocab = (object) array(
          'name' => 'article type',
          'description' => t('Automatically created by the custom_block module'),
          'machine_name' => 'article_type',
          'multiple' => '0',
          'required' => '0',
          'hierarchy' => '1',
          'relations' => '0',
          'module' => 'custom_block',
      );
      taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocab);
      $vid = $vocab->vid

}

  $terms = (object) array (
          'name' => 'News',
          'vid' => $vid,
          'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'article_type',);

 $term_name = $terms -> name;


  $tid = db_query("SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE vid = :vid and name = :name", array(
    ':vid' => $vid,
    ':name' => $term_name,
  ))->fetchField();


if ($vid && !$tid) {

    taxonomy_term_save($terms);
}

}
```

PS:i've figured it out! it's a stupid mistake. i did not get the vid after saving the vocabulary to the database. i just need to add $vid = $vocab->vid after taxonomy_term_save.

Comment: Please add your answer and then later market it as solved. :)

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this. but there seems no option to mark it as solved.

Comment: You have to wait two days to be that available when you answer your own question ;) no worries. I was a newbie too. Welcome to Drupal Answer :D

Answer (score 2):

$vid remains FALSE throughout the entire first run. You need to set it after the vocabulary object is saved:

```
...
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocab);
// Add this next line
$vid = $vocab->vid;
```